# The animation state could not be played because it couldn't be found!

Tags: animation, unity, mecanim

If I try to use animation.Play() or have Play automatically ticked in the inspector on the animtion object, it gives me the follwing error:

The animation state could not be played because it couldn't be found!

I searched around the web and everywhere they say you need set the animation type to 'legacy', but I already changed type to legacy and it did NOT fix the problem.

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you post a screen shot of the hierarchy

Comment: Done. If you need more, just ask!

Comment: Can you also post the script or the part where you play the animation

Comment: http://pastebin.com/QgfsjCWb

Comment: Try deleting the 'this' word before the GetComponent

Comment: No error, no animation. But when I try it in another scene iit works!

Comment: The `this` keyword should not have any affect. It's perfectly legal, just unnecessary.

Comment: If it works in one scene but not another, it sounds like a glitch with the scene not having updated the legacy flag properly. Why not use the newer mecanim method anyway?

Comment: The newer mecanim method?